# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! When trying to combine columns from multiple dataframes in to one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files containing hourly foreign exchange rate data

```
      xDate      xTime    xOpen    xHigh     xLow    xClose     xVolume
   21/10/2002  02:00:00  0.97200  0.97340  0.97190  0.97335        0
   21/10/2002  03:00:00  0.97330  0.97585  0.97320  0.97540        0
   21/10/2002  04:00:00  0.97545  0.97590  0.97470  0.97585        0
   21/10/2002  05:00:00  0.97590  0.97635  0.97480  0.97480        0
   21/10/2002  06:00:00  0.97495  0.97560  0.97460  0.97540        0
```

I want to loop through multiple files and combine the xClose columns in to one dataframe while having the xDate and xTime as indexes.

```
import pandas as pd  

def dFrame (i):
    timeframe = '-1h'
    folder = i + timeframe +'.zip'
    filepath =   'C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/ForexData' + '/' + folder   
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath,names=['xDate','xTime','xOpen','xHigh','xLow','xClose','xVolume'],sep =';',index_col=[0,1])
    return df


tickers = ['audusd','eurusd','gbpusd','nzdusd','usdcad','usdchf','usdjpy']

CombinedCol = pd.DataFrame()

for i in tickers:
    df = dFrame(i)
    df[i] = df.xClose
    CombinedCol[i] = df[i]    

print(CombinedCol)
```

This is the error

```
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

When I drop the index_col=[0,1] from pd.read_csv removing xDate and xTime as indexes I get this output

```
         audusd   eurusd   gbpusd  nzdusd   usdcad   usdchf   usdjpy
0       0.55400  0.97335  1.54810  0.4838  1.57275  1.50985  124.885
1       0.55345  0.97540  1.54940  0.4832  1.57210  1.50745  124.725
2       0.55345  0.97585  1.54950  0.4833  1.57025  1.50655  124.635
3       0.55310  0.97480  1.54795  0.4832  1.56955  1.50765  124.715
4       0.55325  0.97540  1.54780  0.4828  1.57020  1.50680  124.560
```

The above output is exactly what I need except it is missing the date and time as indexes. Is there a way to keep the xDate and xTime as indexes? I have tried various forms of merge and concat but cannot make anything work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem do this:

```
def dFrame(i):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime(2016,6,2)]*i, 'h':np.arange(0,i), 'close':np.random.uniform(0,1, i)})
    df.set_index(['date','h'], inplace=True)
    return df

tickers = ['audusd','eurusd','gbpusd','nzdusd','usdcad','usdchf','usdjpy']
CombinedCol = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(tickers)):
    df = dFrame(i+1)
    CombinedCol = CombinedCol.append(df.close)    

CombinedCol = CombinedCol.T
new_index = list(sum(CombinedCol.index, ()))
CombinedCol.columns = tickers
CombinedCol.index = [new_index[::2], new_index[1::2]]
CombinedCol
```

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I copied and pasted your code and it works, but it won't work with the data I have. I am thinking that in your example your arrays are the same length. My data might have 100,000 rows in one column and 90,000 in another. I wonder if that is what is causing the error?

Comment: I updated using df of different length... let me know